# Using enum with string resources and spinner

Tags: java, android, enums

I want to use enum for my future coding because it seems more legit to me than using strings. Though, I am facing certain problems.

1. I simply want to store a string in a constant and whenever I access it it shall give me the string as output, so I tried the following:

   ```
   public enum Fruit {
       AP("Apple"),
       BA("Banana");

       private String str;

       Fruit(String str) {
           this.str = str;
       }

       public String toString() {
       return str;
       }
   }
   ```

Problem is that whenever I access it, it returns null. Therefore I guess I need to define the value over Fruit() for every single enum before I access them:

```
String fruit = Fruit.AP.toString(); //NULL
```

So I took a different approach:

```
public enum Fruit {
    AP, BA;
    public String toString(){
        switch (this) {
            case AP: return "Apple";
            case BA: return "Banana";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But soon I noticed that it would be more senseful to refer to the string resources, but I could not return `R.string.apple` in the switch. So how can I work around this problem? The first returning null, the second not returning string resources.

2. I want to use these values also in a spinner later on. Is it legit to just use `Fruit.values();`?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is that whenever I access it, it returns null. Therefore I guess I need to define the value over Fruit() for every single enum before I access them:
>
> ```
> String fruit = Fruit.AP.toString(); //NULL
> ```

I see no reason why this should be the case. In fact, if I copy/paste your `enum` definition into my IDE and try to access `Fruit.AP.toString()` I successfully see "Apple" in my output.

The only thing that I see that's concerning is that your `enum` definition includes this:

> ```
> private String str;
> ```

I think you should declare this as `private final String str` instead; you don't want the value of `str` to change over the course of your app's runtime. It's *possible* that something in your code right now is doing something odd like `Fruit.AP.str = null`, and that could be causing your issue.

> But soon I noticed that it would be more senseful to refer to the string resources, but I could not return R.string.apple in the switch. So how can I work around this problem?

You have two choices. Both involve changing your enum definition slightly (something like this):

```
public enum Fruit {

    AP(R.string.apple),
    BA(R.string.banana);

    private final int strId;

    Fruit(int strId strId) {
        this.strId = strId;
    }
}
```

From here, you can either just retrieve the string resource id and then use it like a normal string resource id:

```
myTextView.setText(Fruit.AP.getStrId());
// or
String apple = getString(Fruit.AP.getStrId());
```

Or you can create a method on the enum that accepts a `Context` instance and returns you the string directly:

```
public String getString(Context context) {
    return context.getString(strId);
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
String apple = Fruit.AP.getString(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to the second method with the context?

Comment: Not really. I personally prefer to just return the resource id and let the caller deal with `Context` objects and formatting it.

Comment: How can I use that further on with a spinner? Won't there be any problems considering that I would need to convert all int into strings?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the enum to return the str value

```
public enum Fruit {
    AP("Apple"),
    BA("Banana");

    private String str;

    Fruit(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Which you can then access with `Fruit.AP.getStr();` and that should return what you're after ;)

And yes you can loop through all the values with `Fruit.values();`